# Django 1.9: render cannot pass context to my template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use render(request,'sell.thml',context) in django 1.9, I use mysql to be my database. but nothing show up in my template. I don't know why I cannot use render to pass my context variable to template. Anyone can help me about it?

In my view.py:

```
def sellmainpage(request):
    products=Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        "products": products,
    }
    return render(request, "sell.html", context)
```

In my sell.html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 maincontent" style="padding-top:100px">
<div class="storefront_product_display" >
  {% for product in products %}
  <a href="{% url 'product_detail' %}">
  <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
  <span class="storefront_product_name">{{ product.product }}</span>
  <span class="storefront_product_companyname">{{ product.company }} </span>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

in my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Company)
    description=models.TextField()
    price=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10)
    stock=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

Comment: You have a typo in there. You use `products` in your view but `product` in the template

Comment: @user3100115 yeah, I change the typo, it still not working

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: @trantu that is the problem, I didn't get any errors, just didn't show the context i want to pass to the template

Comment: What is the rendered html? What is the output if you run `print(context)` in your view?

Comment: @Håken Lid 2 . after I print(context):print(context)
{'products': [<Product: fly V>, <Product: Mega>]}

Comment: And what is the rendered html?

Comment: @Håken Lid it is just a empty page with nav-bar and footer.

Comment: @Håken Lid nothing show on the html page

Comment: What is the rendered html? Is there a `<div class="storefront_product_display" >` there or not? Does it have any child elements? I'm not asking how it looks in the browser. What is the output of the template `render()`?

Comment: @Håken Lid after render(), it only have `<div class="storefront_product_display>`.after that, it even not go through the for loop in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Show us your setting, you should have a folder "template", and inside the html

Example settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'template'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'trabajo.context_processors.globales',
                'trabajo.context_processors.menu',
                'trabajo.context_processors.globales',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

you view.py:

```
def sellmainpage(request):
    products=Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        "products": products,
    }
    template = "template/sell.html"
    render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

sell.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`

Comment: this is my settting.py:

Comment: add this line: template = "template/sell.html"
    render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: I follow your idea, I changed but still not working .`from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
import datetime
from .models import Product
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.
def sellmainpage(request):
    template="template/sell.html"
    product=Product.objects.all()
    context=RequestContext(request,{
    'example':product
    })
    return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
`

Comment: replace context=RequestContext(request,{ 'example':product })  with context={ 'example':product }

Comment: yes, I changed it. I post my new view.py, but I still cannot make it work.

Comment: I inspect my template code, I found my template cannot even go though my for loop.

Comment: If you delete the for, can you see the template?

Comment: I try to delete the for, still cannot see any thing, but I try to create a file is context_processor.py, and add the file to setting.py, It work, but I don't know why I cannot use the simple way.

Comment: try to change the template.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
return render(request, "sell.html", context)
```

try

```
loader.get_template('sell.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

don't forget to import needed things.

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
```